# Meaning of "the salesman on the ground"

Tags: meaning, expressions

Please, explain me meaning of "the salesman on the ground".
What does it mean: "door-to-door salesman", "traveling salesman" or "a seller, who works on the first (ground) floor of the store"?

Full sentence, where I read this phrase:

> For the salesman on the ground, selling middling quality to people who wanted the best required tact above all.

Comment: He's the guy who actually talks to customers.

Comment: Some salespeople are in an office, others go and see people.  On the ground is idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oxford dictionaries define *on the ground* as meaning *in a place where real, practical work is done.* It's a metaphor rather than a reference to the salesman's actual place of work.